# Capturar dato de un input de tipo Date en Razor

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Estoy intentando capturar el dato de un input de tipo ***date*** pero no logro conseguir como hacerlo ya que soy bastante nuevo manejando esta tecnología.

`Pregunta principal :` ***¿Cómo hago para capturarlo en Razor?***

Con JavaScript por lo menos no me cuesta hacerlo ya que he manejado bastante JavaScript y pude capturar la fecha pero luego me di cuenta que no podía usar esa variable JavaScript con Razor (C#) ya que según investigue trabajan en distintos ambientes y las variables Razor trabajan del lado del servidor y las de JavaScript del lado del cliente...

`Pregunta opcional:` Aunque según la investigación que hice parece imposible igual pregunto, ***¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo, en este caso capturar el valor de un input con JavaScript y luego usarlo en Razor?***

```
<input class="datefield" id="ReleaseDate" type="date" value="1/11/1989" />
                        @{
                          string dateF = "";
                          dateF = ReleaseDate.Value;
                         }

                        <!-- Codigo Js comentado -->
                        @*<script type="text/javascript">
                            let inputValue;
                            const getValueInput = () => {
                                inputValue = document.getElementById("ReleaseDate").value; 
                                console.log(inputValue)
                            }
                        </script>*@
                        <!-- ----------------- -->

                    <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="getValueInput()">BUSCAR</button>
```

Esto es lo poco que pude hacer, el código JavaScript funciona normal, le doy click al botón y llama a la función y me devuelve en la consola la fecha que escogí.

Mientras que arriba encontre que podia hacerlo asi con Razor `dateF = ReleaseDate.Value`

**Pero me da un error:**
`ReleaseDate` sale subrayado en rojo y me dice que `El nombre ReleaseDate no existe en el contexto actual`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay mucha confusión en tus preguntas.

Tienes el Cliente (navegador) y el servidor, viven en mundos distintos y se comunican mediante solicitudes (del navegador) y la respuesta del servidor. (hay otro métodos pero es otro cuento)

Razor puedes ocuparlo en el cliente si ocupas una tecnología que se llama Blazor, pero entiendo que tu estas en ASP MVC (tendrías que cambiar todo el proyecto)

En respuesta a tus preguntas:

**1) ¿Cómo hago para capturarlo en Razor?**

En ASP MVC no puedes directamente, el que captura las solicitudes es el controlador, luego este puede enviarlo a la vista (Razor)
Es decir tienes que enviar el dato, ya sea, mediante un submit de toda la vida o por ajax

**2) ¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo, en este caso capturar el valor de un input con JavaScript y luego usarlo en Razor?**

Si tú quieres cambiar una porción de la vista en el navegador según haya habido alguna acción del usuario, con ajax y vistas parciales puedes hacerlo.
Tu envías el dato al servidor y el servidor te devuelve una porción de html actualizado, luego al procesar la respuesta reemplazas esa porción en el cliente.

**3? Pero me da un error**

ReleaseDate es el id del input, Razor no lee html lo escribe

Comment: Gracias @Yussef por tu respuesta, voy a tomar en cuenta todo lo que escribiste para ver si consigo una solución al problema, muchas gracias!!

Comment: Si envió la fecha que escogí en el input tipo date con un post en Ajax luego puedo traerla y compararla con una fecha existente en un registro de la base de datos, no?
O sea eso es lo que quiero hacer escoger un fecha y compararla con la columna fechaEmision de un registro en la BD y si son iguales mostrar solo ese registro en la vista.

Comment: @JoseMgz_Ux Claro! Envías por ajax al controlador y el controlador te puede devolver lo que tu quieras. Te puedes devolver un true/false así escondes o no un contenido que ya existe en un cliente. O bien te puede devolver una vista parcial con una porción de código html para que la agregues a tu cliente.